# How is $U=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \mid |x|<1, |y|<2, |z|<3\}$ is open?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that set $U$ is open if every point $p\in U$ has radius $\epsilon_p>0$ about it so that $B_p(\epsilon_p)\subset U$.

Here, $B_p(\epsilon)= \{x\in X:d(x,p)<\epsilon\} $. And $d(x,y)$ has four properties:

1. positivity
2. nondegeneracy
3. homogeneity/symmetry
4. triangle inequality

Comment: Use backslash in front of curly braces, if you want them to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this problem in 3 steps:

1. $\{x:|x|<1\} = \{x: -1<x<1\} = (-1,1)$
2. $\{(x,y): |x|<1, |y|<2\} = \{(x,y): -1<x<1, -2<y<2\} = (-1,1) \times (-2,2)$
3. $\{(x,y,z): |x|<1,|y|<2,|z|<1\} =\cdots = (-1,1) \times (-2,2) \times 
   (-3,3)$

All of which are products of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take a point $t = (x,y,z)\in U$ and prove that $ B_r(t')$ is contained in $U$, where $t' = (\frac{x+1}{2}, \frac{y+2}{2}, \frac{z+3}{2})$ and $r = \dfrac{\min(|x-1|/2, |2-y|/2, |z-3|/2) }{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Pick a metric that seems convenient...say, $d(\mathbf p, \mathbf q) = max (|x_p-x_q|,|y_p-y_q|,|z_p - z_q|)$

Show that this is a valid metric.  You have the definition.

$\epsilon = min(\frac {|1-|x_p|}2,\frac {2-|y_p|}2, \frac {3-|z_p|}2)$

$\forall \mathbf q\in B_p(\epsilon), q\in U$

Answer (score 0):

Take any point $p=(x,y,z)$ of your set $U$, then the open ball $B_p(\epsilon)$ is contained in $U$, if  you define $\epsilon=\min\{d(p,(1,y,z)),d(p,(x,2,z)),d(p,(x,y,3)), d(p,(-1,y,z)),d(p,(x,-2,z)),d(p,(x,y,-3))\}$